# What is the default idle timeout for angular application?

Tags: angular, angular7

I have a page which shows some list of data in popup on some action. This works fine on flow. After some idle time if i click the button the list is getting empty. is there default time that angular holds the data? Currently i am using angular 7.

Comment: There's no timeout, but you don't provide an example , so we have no idea of WTF you're doing to make you think there is.

Answer (score 0):

If you can reproduce your problem with a code sample ideally something runnable (blitzstack perhaps) we can answer your question better. With the minimal information provided its difficult to help.

Generally with an Angular app everything is transferred to the client and running there so there shouldn't be any timeout. Perhaps its an issue with the library you're using for the "popup" or perhaps its just a code branch that's run on the second click